# Placement of "before" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I know  it is correct to say,

> "I have often been to the UK."

How about this?

> **I had often been to the UK before.**

Does that still sound natural?

Comment: It might sound a little awkward with that verb ("had often been"), but it sounds fine in sentences like, "I've been to the UK before."

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more natural to replace "before" with something like "in the past".
I had often been to the UK in the past. I haven't gone for a long time.

The sentence needs "something like a reason" following "before".
I had often been to the UK before the flights became so expensive.
I had often been to the UK before I had children.

Or, easier to use a simple location word, such as Disneyland.

> I have often been to Disneyland. 
>  I had often been to Disneyland before the tickets became so expensive. 
>  I had often been to Disneyland before my kids grew up.

Comment: Oh !  got It !!!

Comment: I think it mostly sounds awkward because of the word "often". Take that out, and the sentence sounds fine with just a "before" at the end, as in: "I've been to Disneyland before."

Answer (score 0):

I think it sounds natural to use "before". Please look at the following sentences:

"I had often/four times been to the UK before I went to do a PhD".